# Chainerでネットワークの途中でのデータの合成方法は？

Tags: python, 深層学習, chainer, ニューラルネットワーク

Deep learningのChainerを使ってDeeplearningの勉強をしています。
その過程で、２つのデータを組み合わせることをやりたいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

具体的には、

```
def forward(x1,x2):
    h1 = F.relu(model.l1(x1))
    h2 = F.relu(model.l2(x2))

    h = F.relu(model.l3(???))
```

Model1とModel2のデータを合成し（[x1 x2]のように２つのベクトルを縦に並べた長いベクトルを作る）、Model3に入れたいと考えています。

Chainerの変数はVariableを使っており通常のNumpyの vstack、hstack が使えません。どうすればいいかわからなかったため、教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`chainer.functions.concat`を使って下さい。引数`axis`でどの次元でconcatするかを指定できます。以下のサンプルを参考にしてみて下さい。

```
In [2]: x1 = chainer.Variable(numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))

In [3]: x2 = chainer.Variable(numpy.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]]))

In [4]: x1.data
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [5]: x2.data
Out[5]: 
array([[5, 6],
      [7, 8]])

In [6]: chainer.functions.concat([x1, x2], axis=1).data
Out[6]: 
array([[1, 2, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Concatというコマンドがあったのですね。見つけれませんでした。
ネットワークを回したところ上手くいきました。ありがとうございました。